# Bad argument "postrouting" in firewall script "centos"

Tags: linux, unix, centos, firewall

Hey there i have this firewall "IPtables" script on a virtual machine that run cent'os.

it says bad argument "postrouting"

[image]

And i cant ping from my other virual machine's and i have tested ping before i had run the script.

Here is my network map of my virtal machines:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong

```
iptables -t nat POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 10.224.67.X
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I THINK i found the solution:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 10.224.67.X

but i still can't ping :P